# I moved a Kolsch to secondary after 4 days. Should I repitch yeast?

Tags: yeast, fermentation

This is my first batch ever, a Kolsch from a kit. It fermented like crazy the first 2 days, but after 4 had stopped bubbling, so I moved it to a secondary container. As I was transferring, I noticed a thick layer of lumpy light-tan sediment at the bottom of the primary, which I did not transfer. Is this where most of the yeast was? I'm now worried that there might not be enough yeast in the secondary to complete a proper amount of fermentation.

Also complicating matters is that a friend advised that I didn't need to take the OG reading.

So should I add more yeast into this secondary container?

Comment: I too have had a similar situation. Fermented in primary for about a week. very little action from the airlock then transfered to seconday while (new idea- straining through a screen sifter thinking it would help to clearify the beer). well after a week or so, I had seen no action from the airlock and was affraid either I filtered all the yeast out or would have contaminated beer since no purging of air had happened in the secondary. Ideas of pitching new yeast crossed my mind but since I boiled the wort to high of a temp and figured I ruined it anyway, I scrapped the batch. newbee beer maker

Comment: OG from a extract kit isn't always strictly necessary - if you use all of the extract and add top-up water to the right volume and added any sugars needed, you're pretty much assured you hit the OG. But even so, taking as much data as you can will make troubleshooting later easier.

Answer (score 3):

There should be more than enough yeast still in suspension to continue the job.  4 days is actually a little short for transferring to a secondary and you're going to end up with more sediment, or trub, in your carboy.  Assuming there are no extreme changes in temperature, you don't need to worry about the yeast until several weeks into fermenting.  Give the Kolsch a couple weeks in the carboy and it should be clear enough for looks, but still have enough yeast in suspension for bottling.